# Hoffman and Kunze, Linear Algebra Sec 2.5 Exercise 6

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Let $V$ be the vector space over the complex  numbers of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{C}.$ Let $f_1(x)=1,f_2(x)=e^{ix},f_3(x)=e^{-ix}.$ Prove that $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are linearly independent.

Attempt: Suppose there exists scalars $c_1,c_2,c_3$ such that $c_1+c_2e^{ix}+c_3e^{-ix}=0,\forall x\in \mathbb{R}.$

For $x=0,$ we get $c_1+c_2+c_3=0$

For $x=\pi,$ we get $c_1-c_2-c_3=0$

For $x=\pi/2,$ we get $c_1+ic_2-ic_3=0$

Solving this system of equations we get $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$

**Is this proof valid?**

Comment: Almost certainly.

Comment: Of course it is. Not only that, it is very probably the shortest, clearest one.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is completely valid!

I'll mention that another common method to prove this statement is to differentiate the equation you started with to get $i c_2 e^{ix} - i c_3 e^{-ix} = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and then differentiate again to get $ -c_2 e^{ix} - c^3 e^{-ix} = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, substitute any convenient $x$, say $x = 0$, and then solve the corresponding system of equations:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & i & -i \\
0 & -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1\\
c_2\\
c_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to get $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0$.